# Semantic UI dropdown values cannot be accessed

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

This is an issue related to Semantic UI's dropdowns at https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html.

I have a bunch of multiselect dropdowns defined and have declared the line

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
```

well before doing any sort of operations with the dropdowns, in order to activate the dropdowns' behavior. Curiously, however,

1. when I try using certain methods on the dropdown, such as `$("#" + mydropdown.id).dropdown("get text")`, I get an error in the Chrome Dev Tools, saying "Uncaught TypeError: No method named "get text".
2. But when I try to simply use `$("#" + mydropdown.id).dropdown()`, it works: I am able to access the dropdown element without any issue whatsoever.

What could be the cause? I am absolutely clueless as to why this could be happening. Any hypotheses as to what could be happening are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, the problem above was solved by commenting out a line of code that referenced `bootstrap.in.js`. I've heard that Bootstrap could interfere with Semantic UI, and I disabled Bootstrap.js in another application, but for some reason I forgot to do so within the current app.